# Custom Pluging Entries FieldType

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, fieldtypes, custom-fieldtype, custom

I have 2 plugins I created that store similar data:

Plugin 1: `id, name, panel_id, price`

Plugin 2: `id, name, test_id, price`

I want to attach my plugin data to an entry, and I need to make sure they can only select one Panel or Test. I want to know if there is a way to add them as a source for Entries as a new field. Or can I create a similar custom fieldtype to be used for both plugins and have that kind of validation?

I'm using Craft V2.6

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Relation Field](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/element-types.html#relations) for each of your element types and include a custom js rule so if one of them has a value, the other one can't be selected.

The more difficult way would be to extend the field and the `ElementSelectModal` and the `ElementIndex` to select multiple element types but this is going to be a little bit more tricky since you'll need a custom controller to fetch all elements and can't rely on the `ElementsController`

Comment: Is there a similar feature on craft 2?

Comment: Yes there is the same field just with slightly different logic

Comment: Haven't been able to found the equivalent.

Comment: Take a look at `craft/app/fieldtypes/EntriesFieldType` and the class it extends

Comment: So I create a new FieldType that Extends `BaseElementFieldType` ? and the class should be on both plugins under the folder fieldtype? something like: `Plugin1_TestFieldType` and `Plugin2_TestFieldType` ?

Comment: Yeah, As I said, you can take a look at `craft/app/fieldtypes/EntriesFieldType` all you need to do is to change the `protected $elementType = 'Entry';` to your custom Element type. Each for your elements will have their custom field type. You can then include JS somewhere that checks if both field types exists and if so remove the content from the other one on select

Comment: ok. so I will have two different Fields and then I have to add some custom JS to check and avoid the selection of both.